# Disable jsessionid via http header (cookie) in Tomcat 7

Tags: session, tomcat, tomcat7, jsessionid

I'm looking to disable jsessionid from being used in the https headers.
Is there a way to turn this off or disable this being set as a cookie in tomcat 7?

I either want the jsessionid to arrive embedded into a GET method url name value pairs or to be part of a POST request name value pairs.

I know all the advantages and disadvantages of using cookie based sessioning and url rewriting but I have specific needs for specific impl of restful web services.

I need tomcat 7 to accept jsessionid without using the http header: jsessionid.

Thanks.

**UPDATE:**

so I looked around some more and found [this](http://java.sun.com/javaee/6/docs/api/javax/servlet/SessionTrackingMode.html) which is implemented using the web.xml conf.
However the following doesn't seem to work with Tomcat 7.

```xml
<session-config>
    <tracking-mode>URL</tracking-mode>
</session-config>
```

is it a case of TC7 not fully implementing the servlet 3.0 spec?

Answer (score 4):

The `web.xml` setting works for me with Tomcat 7.0.20.

Log and check the effective (and maybe the default) session tracking modes:

```
logger.info("default STM: {}" , servletContext.getDefaultSessionTrackingModes());
logger.info("effective STM: {}" , servletContext.getEffectiveSessionTrackingModes());
```

Maybe your app override somewhere in the code the session tracking modes. An example:

```
final Set<SessionTrackingMode> trackingModes = 
    Collections.singleton(SessionTrackingMode.COOKIE);
servletContext.setSessionTrackingModes(trackingModes);
```

Check [ServletContext.setSessionTrackingModes()](http://java.sun.com/javaee/6/docs/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#setSessionTrackingModes%28java.util.Set%29) calls in your code.

It's also possible [to set default session tracking modes in the Tomcat's context settings](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/context.html) but I found that `web.xml` settings override them.